How to troubleshoot the "Neither port nor sslPort specified" error in Ktor
What could be the reasons for the following error when a server application bundled into a fat JAR is launched?
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Neither port nor sslPort specified. Use command line options -port/-sslPort or configure connectors in application.conf


The first and most obvious reason is that the application.conf and application.yaml files are missing from the classpath. You can check the presence of those files by decompiling the JAR file, for example, with JD-GUI.
The second reason is that the ktor-server-config-yaml dependency is included in the build, along with the YamlConfigLoader service class, but only the application.conf file is present. This can be solved by removing the ktor-server-config-yaml dependency from the build to make the server load the application.conf file.
If the application.yaml file is expected to be loaded, the error shows that either the file is missing or the ktor-server-config-yaml dependency isn't included in the build. To fix the issue, add the missing file and include the ktor-server-config-yaml dependency to the build if needed.
The general problem with the configuration files in Ktor is the opaque mechanism for choosing the loader and the acceptance of an empty configuration.
